# Surface area of a cone using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals, cylindrical-coordinates

I know this question was asked already, but I would really like to resolve some problems I still have with it.

An area element in cylindrical coordinate is  $\quad rd \theta dz  \quad $  and $ \quad r = R(1- \frac{z}{h}) $

So why can't I write

$$ S = \int_{0}^{2 \pi}   \int_{0}^{h} r(z) d\theta dz = \quad   \int_{0}^{2 \pi}   \int_{0}^{h}  R(1- \frac{z}{h}) d\theta dz = \quad \pi Rh $$

If I divide the cone into small rings with radius  $  r_i $, then the area of each ring is

$$ 2\pi r_i \Delta z$$

Taking the sum of all rings,  $$ \sum_{i=0}^{N} 2\pi r_i \Delta z$$
And in the limit $N \to \infty $ :
$$ 2 \pi  \int_{0}^{h} r(z) dz$$

What's wrong about it? I understand that the problem is in the infinitesimal area that was used, that I didn't take into account the slant of the cone.

But, when we integrate $ y = x $ we also don't consider the slant, because for smaller and smaller $\Delta x's$ the area aproaches the correct area.
Why is it not the case when dividing the cone into slantless rings?

Setting $y = x$ into $ \int ydx$ is taking into account the slope, the different height in each place, then why is it not enough to set $ r = R(1- \frac{z}{h})$ into the integral? what is the difference between those to examples?

I would really like some intuitive explnation to understand the differences.

[image]

Comment: There is a problem with your first formula. Instead of $dz$, you should have $dl$, where $l$ is along the surface. See for example https://socratic.org/questions/how-to-get-surface-area-of-a-cone-using-integral-calculus or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18226/setting-up-an-integral-to-find-a-cones-surface-area

Comment: @Andrei I was refering to it,  please read the end of my question.

Comment: The difference is that when you calculate area, by making smaller $\Delta x$ you approximate better and better the area under the curve. But try to calculate the length of the segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. You can't just integrate $dx$ from $0$ to $1$. In your problem, the ratio between the area of the infinitesimally thin disk and the disk height is **different** than the ratio between the area of a frustum and the height.

Comment: @Andrei Is taking thinner rings won't approximate better the area of each ring to the area of a frustum? Why is it like integrating $dx$ from $0$ to $1$? I'm not using the same $r$ in every ring, so how is it like taking the same height and sum it from $0$ to $1$? Why is the ratio you mentioned important?

Comment: Let's assume that you know the area of a frustum: $$A=\pi(r_1+r_2)\sqrt{(r_1-r_2)^2+h^2}$$You can take $h$ outside of the square root:$$A=2\pi\frac{r_1+r_2}2h\sqrt{1+\frac{(r_1-r_2)^2}{h^2}}$$When you take the limit $h\to 0$, $r_1$ is close to $r_2$, but $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{r_1-r_2}h$ is a constant for a cone (the slope of the cone).

Comment: Related: [Areas versus volumes of revolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6979/21813)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, when we integrate y=x we also don't consider the slant, because for smaller and smaller Δx′s the area ap[p]roaches the correct area.

Yes, the *area* of the rectangles under the line approaches the correct area.  But the length of the *lines* formed by the tops of the rectangles doesn't approach the true length of the diagonal line.  It's a staircase shape, and will *always* have a length of $x+y$ (i.e., the combined length of the horizontal segments plus the combined length of the vertical segments) no matter how small you make the "stairs".

It's the exact fallacy committed [in this fake proof that $\pi=4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4).

Similarly, while the combined *volume* of the discs does approach the volume of the cone, the combined *surface area* does not approach the surface area of the cone.