# Solids of revolution using cone frusta

Tags: calculus

I was interested by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/areas-versus-volumes-of-revolution) in finding the volume of a solid of revolution using a "more accurate" cone frustum instead of the usual cylindrical disk.

So, starting with the volume of a cone frustum $ V = \frac{\pi}{3} ( R^2 + r^2 + Rr ) $, compute:

[image: conical frusta]
$$
\frac{\pi}{3}(  (r+ \Delta y)^2 + r^2 + (r+ \Delta y)(r)  ) \Delta x
$$

$$
= \frac{\pi}{3}(  3r^2 + 3 r \Delta y + \Delta y^2  ) \Delta x
$$

Which is interesting, because the regular disk formula comes out if you ignore the $ \Delta y $ terms, which means you're assuming the cone is actually a cylinder.

I'm not sure how to finish this though!  How can I work with $ \Delta y $ to create an integral formula?

Comment: Typically, you're working with the graph of some function so that, for instance, $r=f(x)$.  This would make $r+\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)$, so $\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$.  Now, if we go back to your final expression,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{3}( & 3r^2 + 3 r \Delta y + \Delta y^2  ) \Delta x
\\
&= \frac{\pi}{3}(  3(f(x))^2 + 3 f(x) (f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)) + (f(x+\Delta x)-f(x))^2  ) \Delta x
\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3}(2f(x)f(x+\Delta x)+(f(x+\Delta x))^2+(f(x))^2)\Delta x
\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3}(f(x)+f(x+\Delta x))^2\Delta x
\end{align}$$ but that seems wrong I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @Isaac: The 2 in the next to last line of your derivation should not be there. Compare the original volume formula.

Comment: @Niels: Ahh!  Okay, so the end line could be written as $$\frac{\pi}{3}\left((f(x)+f(x+\Delta x))^2-f(x)f(x+\Delta x)\right)\Delta x,$$ which at least feels more plausible because it collapses to something very much like $\pi(f(x))^2\;dx$ when $\Delta x\to 0$.

Comment: @Nils your comment can be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assuming that $r$  varies continuously with  $x$, you get that $\Delta y \to 0$  as  $\Delta x \to 0$.

So in the limit you get 
$$
\frac{dV}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\pi ( 3r^2 + 3 r \Delta y + \Delta y^2) \Delta x}{3 \Delta x} = \pi r^2
$$