# Computing the surface area of a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area, spheres

Filling a hemisphere with cylinders as so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5VRS.png

Now, if the radius of the sphere is R and radius of the disk(r) at any given height y is:

$$r = \sqrt{R^2 - y^2}$$

Now the sum of all the areas on the side of the cylinders i.e the surface area of a hemisphere must be:

$$\int_0^R 2\pi rdy$$
or
$$\int_0^R 2\pi \sqrt{R^2 - y^2}dy$$

this solves to $$\frac{\pi^2 R^2}{2} $$
which for the sphere is $$\pi^2 R^2$$

Comment: The areas on the side of the cylinders look wrong. [Spoiler](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1659387/949989). Also: the end result should probably depend on $R$ rather than $r\,.$

Comment: How? 2piR is the circumference multiplied by some dy thickness, what's wrong with that?

Comment: That thickness is different at every level of $y\,.$ It is not always $dy\,.$ A very common mistake. Draw a picture. You have the Spoiler just in case.

Comment: dy is the thickness of the cylinder placed at y, another cylinder at different y will also have thickness dy but y or distance from the xz plane may change.

Comment: Ok. I know what you mean. The radius of each "cylinder" is $r=\sqrt{R^2-y^2}\,.$ Its surface area is $2\pi r\sqrt{dy^2+dr^2}\,.$

Comment: Wouldn't the surface area just be 2*pi*r*dy

Comment: and What is dr here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150026/discussion-between-rummy-rummyrum-and-kurt-g).

Comment: No. I gave enough hints. Think more carefully about the slope of your "cylinder" surface. Apply Pythagoras. Here on MSE you find dozens of posts where that common question is handled.

Answer (score 0):

This is a big problem that beginners run into while calculating areas and such integrals where it is correct to take your given element in hindsight but is actually incorrect (useful for maybe mathematics or even in physics).

So the problem lies in the fact that to find the surface area of an object with curved surface, the element must cover **all** of the surface and while integrating, nothing from the object's surface is left. Let us take an example of the surface area of a cone (because that is easier to draw in powerpoint)

What I mean by this is : look at [this image (consider it to be 3d)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zA6A.png). According to your method, the surface area of the disk $ = \frac{2\pi Ry\;dy}{H}$ and then you would integrate this to get the surface area of the cone. This is clearly incorrect as you may now see because we are forgetting the fact that the cone has a slanted surface and to really take the surface area at a height y nd spanning a width dy, we must have the disk slanted. What I mean is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDbu7.png). So if we now see the surface area of the disk, it will not be $ = \frac{2\pi Ry\;dy}{H}$. Since the disk spans a very small width, so we can assume the slanted height to be the vertical height of a new disk (radius is same because change in radius is negligible in this height change) (so that we can write the surface area of that disk = surface area of a new disk $= 2\pi (radius)(vertical\;height)$). [After calculating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIRKf.png) we get the correct surface area of the disk $ = \frac{2\pi Ry\;dl}{H} = \frac{2\pi Ry\;dy \sqrt{1 + \frac{R^2}{H^2}}}{H}$. Integrate this and you will get the correct surface area of the cone.

Similiarly with the suface area of the sphere (let radius of sphere is r), the disk you [took](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU9M0.png) is not "slanted" and so you would have to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ufO.png). [After calculating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u0hS.png) the correct surface area of the disk and integrating the expression $ = 2\pi R\;dl = 2\pi r\sin (\theta)\;\frac{dy}{\sin (\theta)} = 2\pi r dy$ (y goes from -r to +r), we get te correct surface area of the sphere $= 4\pi r^2$ (for hemisphere, y goes from 0 to r so you can just halve the area of the sphere)