# How to calculate the geometric center of the surface-area of a part of a Sphere?

Tags: geometry, spheres

I have a regular sphere, $V=\pi r^3\frac4 3$ and $A=4\pi r^2$. Now I want to seperate it into four slices, with equal amounts of surface area - not counting the sliced area.

Or in other words, I want to find the distance from the bottom of half a sphere, where above and below have the same surface area.

I started by making a formular that describes the circumference of a slice, depending on the distance from center: $s=\pi \sqrt{(r^2-x^2)}$. So at the bottom, the circumference is $\pi r^2$, and at the top $0$. Makes sense. Now my approach was to integrate that from 0 to v after x, and set this equal to $A/4 = \pi r^2$. So $r^2 = \int_0^v \sqrt{(r^2-x^2)} dx$. This does not however give any meaningful solution it seems. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The area of a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) is $\pi rh$, where $h$ is the distance from top to bottom of the cap. Hence you must simply divide the diameter of the sphere into four equal parts.

To understand why your computation doesn't work, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830662/i-want-to-know-if-the-way-i-derived-the-surface-area-of-a-sphere-by-integration/1830693#1830693).