# Why doesn't $2\pi\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ give the surface area of a sphere of radius $1$?

Tags: calculus, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Areas versus volumes of revolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/areas-versus-volumes-of-revolution)

For fun I decided to derive the surface area of a sphere of radius $1$ from the formula for the perimeter of a circle.  This integral is what I came up with:

$$2\pi\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \pi^2$$

Unfortunately the desired value is $4\pi$.  My rationale was simply to stack infinitely thin 'hula-hoops' whose radii followed the curvature of the sphere.  I can't readily see where my conceptual misunderstandings are, can someone help elucidate them for me? Thanks.

Comment: These hula hoops will be parallel to the $x$ axis I presume. They need to be slanted! Imagine measuring a the length of a graph on the inverval $[a,b]$ by adding little line segments to the curve parallel to the $x$-axis: the sum of these lengths will simply be $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and links, they've been a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the surface area for a surface of revolution formula
$$2\pi\int \rho\,ds,$$
where $ds$ is an element of arc length.  The smart way to go is to parametrize the 
semicircle as follows, $x(t) = \cos(t)$, $y(t) = \sin(t)$.

We have 
$$ds = \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} = 1. $$

The quantity $\rho$ is the radius of the surface of revolution, which, in this case, is
$y = \sin(t)$.

For the circle

$$\sigma = 2\pi\int_0^\pi \sin(t)\,dt = 2\pi(2) = 4\pi.$$

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps : Surface area $S$ is given by $$ S= \int_{0}^{\pi}2\pi rdt$$ Where $$dt=Rd\theta$$ and $$ r=Rsin\theta$$ $\theta$ being the angle of the circle in question . So we get $$ S= \int_{0}^{\pi}2\pi R^2sin\theta d\theta $$ $$S= 4\pi$$