# Attempting to compute *surface* of solid of revolution

Tags: integration, area, solid-of-revolution

I saw that in order to compute the volume of a surface of revolution, we can use $\int_a^b\pi f^2\left(x\right)dx$, where $f$ is the curve to be rotated. This seemed really intuitive: for each "slice" (i.e: for each value of $x$) we look at the curve's value, $f(x)$, as the radius of a circle (since we're going to rotate it, so that area is exactly our eventual solid's intersection with the plane $x=$whichever value we're currently looking at), and then compute its area with $\pi f(x)^2$, and perform integration over all of those slices to end up with our volume. I'm aware this is not remotely rigorous, but I thought it was a relatively safe intuitive explanation for why it works.
I then tried to apply this same logic to compute the solid's *surface* area, but here it came apart. Specifically, what I attempted to claim was that if instead of integrating over the areas of the discs, I just integrated over their perimeters, I'd end up with the surface; so:
$\int_a^b 2 \pi f(x) dx$
Surprisingly for me but probably not for anyone else reading this, that didn't work! :(
I was hoping for an explanation as to why, exactly, and if there's some tweak I could perform to make it work. I looked online and couldn't see anything close to this; I did find another formula with derivatives under a square root, but I failed to find something to help me reason about the fault in my logic here.

In case this is relevant: what I'd attempted to do is compute the surface area of half a sphere; so I integrated with $f(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ from $x=0$ to $x=r$.
This gives $\int_0^r \pi (1-x^2)dx = \frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$ as the volume, which is awesome!
But $\int_0^r \sqrt{r^2-x^2}dx = \frac{\pi r^2}{4}$ as the surface area, which is unfortunate.

Comment: What you've got here is a 3D analogue of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staircase_paradox

Comment: Recall the lateral surface area of the right cone with radius r and height h. It is not $\pi r h$ but $\pi r\sqrt{h^2+r^2}$.

Comment: Note that to compute the volume of a curve being rotated can be done by dividing the region into differential cylinders, to compute the surface area of a curve being rotated one needs to integrate all the surface elements $dA$: $$ dA = \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2} ydx d\phi$$

Comment: There have been lots of posts here about this "paradox." Go back down to understanding arclength. What happens if you try to add up pieces $\Delta x$ instead of $\Delta s = \sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2}\Delta x$ to find the length of $y=f(x)$? Draw pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, guys. Also, the staircase paradox just blew my mind a little; never thought about this!

Comment: In my opinion, the only *sensible* way to calculate the volume and surface area of a body of revolution is with Pappus's Centroid Theorems. I've explained this many times previously, see here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275671/surface-area-vs-volume-of-solid-of-revolution/2276841#2276841) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: This is explained in every calculus textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can hopefully help you to see the fault in your logic by using some "physicist's thinking" — not very rigorous, but perhaps more illustrative (and hopefully the real mathematicians here won't tear me apart for this).

Here's a super-rough sketch by hand:

[image]

This is a sketch of one of your "slices" enclosed between two very close planes in heights $z$ and $z + \mathrm{d}z$, where by $\mathrm{d}z$ I mean an infinitesimally small increment of $z$. The distance of the curve from the axis of rotation is $r$ in the lower plane and slightly different $r + \mathrm{d} r$ in the upper one.

So what happens when you calculate the volume of the slice? You just calculate the volume of a small cylinder with radius $r$ and height $\mathrm{d} z$, getting $\pi r^2\,\mathrm{d} z$. Notice that in the sketch, this is the rectangle with two black horizontal and two blue vertical lines. So by counting like that, we're essentially "throwing away" the little colorful triangles.

Why do we get the correct answer? It's because the triangles are way too small and they give zero volume when rotated. You can intuitively see that just by looking at the areas in the sketch: you count the volume that corresponds to the black/blue rectangle with area $r\,\mathrm{d} z$, and throw away the triangle with area $\tfrac12 \mathrm{d} r\,\mathrm{d}z$. So the volume of the slice is infinitesimally small, and the volume of the triangle is infinitesimally small *with respect to that infinitesimally small slice*. It's "infinitesimally small squared"; no wonder it doesn't contribute.

However: when you calculate the surface area with your method, you're still counting the surface area of the little cylinders (i. e. the blue bits in the sketch). Sadly, that won't do, because the "real surface" is the orange one. And you're using $\mathrm{d} z$ where you should really use the length of the sloped orange line, which is $\sqrt{\mathrm{d} z^2 + \mathrm{d} r^2}$ (just apply the Pythagorean theorem to the colorful triangle). $\mathrm{d} r$ and $\mathrm{d} z$ are pretty similar in magnitude, so you can't just throw one of them out and expect to get away with it — it's like saying that $\sqrt2$ is pretty much equal to $1$ because $\sqrt2 = \sqrt{1 + 1}$ and we can neglect one of the $1$'s!

So, taking your half-sphere $r = \sqrt{R^2 - z^2}$, we first need to calculate

$$ \mathrm{d} r = \frac{\mathrm d (R^2 - z^2)}{2\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} = \frac{- z\,\mathrm d z}{\sqrt{R^2 - z^2}}. $$

And the surface area of the slice is essentially the surface of a cylinder with radius $r$ and height $\sqrt{\mathrm d z^2 + \mathrm d r^2}$, so it needs to be

$$ \mathrm{d} S = 2\pi r \sqrt{\mathrm d z^2 + \mathrm d r^2} = 2\pi \sqrt{R^2 - z^2} \times \sqrt{\mathrm d z^2 + \frac{z^2}{R^2 - z^2} \mathrm d z^2} = 2\pi R |\mathrm d z|. $$

Integrate this from $z = 0$ to $z = R$ to get the $2\pi R^2$ that we know is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that's super informative and helpful. I arrived at my false formula with dollar-store "physicist's thinking", and I think some higher quality form of it is just what I needed to feel better about this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to "add up small patches of surface" whereas your intuitive approach ends up just adding up lengths - it neglects the "local stretching of the curve".

I'll put a bunch of explanations up front because I think they might be helpful but maybe the very end is enough already.

###### How to get the volume formula

Let's go back to square one and consider the volume case: assume we have a positive function $f$ then we can parametrize the solid of revolution obtained from this $f$ as
$$
\psi(x, r, \phi) = \pmatrix{x \\ r f(x) \cos(\phi) \\ r f(x)\sin(\phi) }
$$
where $x$ ranges over some interval $(x_1, x_2)$, $r$ from $0$ to $1$ and $\phi$ over the angles you want which is also an interval; and for simplicity I'll use $(0, 2\pi)$ here.
We get the volume of our solid by integrating over it - but we somehow want to use this map $\psi$ to do this integration because it's a quite natural expression of this solid that is likely to simplify the calculation.

We can think about what's happening with this map $\psi$ like this: we have a rectangular prism in a space with axes $x, r, \phi$ and $\psi$ molds this prism into our solid of revolution by somehow shaping these weird axes into the regular cartesian ones. If we knew how much $\psi$ "stretched" space while doing so, then we could use this information to relate the volume of this cube to the volume of the solid of revolution in some way. Since the stretching could really differ from one point to the next we gotta consider the local stretching of $\psi$ at each point in $x,r,\phi$ space.

It turns out that this local stretching factor is precisely the (absolute value of the) [jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) of $\psi$ (there's some great geometric explanations for this). Denoting our solid of revolution by $S$ and the prism by $C$ we have $S=\psi(C)$ and find the formula
$$
\int_S ~dS = \int_{\psi(C)} ~d(\psi(C)) = \int_C | \det J_\psi| ~dC = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} |\det J_\psi(x,r,\phi)| ~d\phi ~dr ~dx.
$$
If we actually calculate the jacobian we find that
$$
J_\psi(x, r, \phi) = \pmatrix{1  & 0 & 0 \\ rf'(x) \cos(\phi) & f(x) \cos(\phi) & -rf(x)\sin(\phi) \\ rf'(x) \sin(\phi)) & f(x) \sin(\phi) & rf(x)\cos(\phi)}
$$
and using a Laplace expansion the determinant of this is easily found to equal $rf(x)^2$. Plugging this into the integral above then yields the formula you already know:
$$
\int_S ~dS = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} rf(x)^2 ~d\phi ~ dr~dx = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)^2~dx \int_0^1 r ~dr \int_0^{2\pi} ~d\phi = \pi \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)^2~dx
$$

###### How to get the surface area formula

Okay let's repeat this for the area: we again set up a parametrisation of the surface of revolution. This time we only have to parameters: we eliminate the parameter $r$ from the previous one by simply setting it to $1$. We have
$$
\psi(x, \phi) = \pmatrix{x \\f(x) \cos(\phi) \\f(x) \sin(\phi)}.
$$
We already know how to do these calculations now: we simply calculate the jacobian determinant and integrate it over $x$ and $\phi$... the problem is that $J_\psi$ won't be square and doesn't have a determinant in the usual sense: $\psi$ doesn't just stretch space to go from the one with axes $x, \phi$ to the usual cartesian space; it has to add a whole new dimension.

Phrased differently: it takes a 2-dimensional rectangle, stretches it in some way and places this stretched piece of surface into cartesian space. Using this phrasing we can work out the appropriate scaling factor using a kind of [QR-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) we get from an [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition). Omitting the details we find that the appropriate factor is the so-called Gramian determinant $\sqrt{\det (J_\psi^T J_\psi)}$. You can informally think of this kinda like this: we go from 2D to 3D space using $J_\psi$ and apply the stretching factor once while doing so. Then we go from 3D back to 2D using $J_\psi^T$ which has the same stretching factor. We then take the square root to get the value that a single stretching has.

The jacobian in this case is
$$
J_\psi(x, \phi) = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\f'(x) \cos(\phi) & -f(x)\sin(\phi) \\f'(x) \sin(\phi) & f(x) \cos(\phi)}
$$
and after a bit of a calculation we find that the gramian determinant of this is
$$
|f(x)|\sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2}
$$
which is probably the expression with the square root of the derivative you've already found. Since we assumed $f$ to be positive we can drop the absolute value from this expression. Plugging this into our integral we then find
$$
\int_S ~dS = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} ~d\phi ~dx = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} 2\pi f(x) \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} ~dx.
$$

##### Analyzing the area formula

The $2\pi f(x)$ in this integral is precisely the circumference of the circle that you already expected to play some part. The extra factor here is $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$ - what's up with that? This term is exactly the ["length element" of the graph of $f$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integration) (you can find this using the same method of parametrising and integrating the gramian determinant; just that you'll only have one parameter this time).

This element tells us something about the arc length of the graph of $f$. So at any point we're really considering the circumference you found, multiplied by the length of a small line segment along the bounding curve. So we've intuitively chopped up the surface into a bunch of cylindrical shells and sum up their respective surface areas to get the whole thing.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this – that was a really interesting explanation showing intimate connections between areas I've heard of completely independently. Thanks a lot for this; I'll definitely look more into it :) I marked Ramillies's answer because the visual/physicist explanation happens to be closer to what I've been looking for, but your answer shows me things I didn't even know I was* looking for until now, which is amazing!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

To compute the surface area $A$ of a function $y(x)$ revolving about the $x$-axis we integrate all differential surface elements $dA = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}y d\phi$ of the surface of revolution:

$$ A = \int dA = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_a^b \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2} y dxd\phi$$

As an example we take the (half) circle $y = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. Taking the derivative we get:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}}$$

Substituting into the first equation we get:

$$ A = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{x^2}{r^2 - x^2} \right)} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} dx d\phi $$

$$ = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{\left( \frac{r^2}{r^2 - x^2} \right)} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} dx d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-r}^r r dx d\phi = 4 \pi r^2 $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'll look into this!